# Drupal - Dispaly block if term page has no tagged nodes and no child terms?

Tags: drupal-6

How can I show a block on term pages if no nodes are tagged with that term and also there are no child terms?

Im using Drupal 6. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tricky one but you could use custom PHP code for your block display, something like this (assuming Drupal 6 here):

```
if (strstr($_GET['q'], 'taxonomy/term/')) {
  $parts = explode('/', $_GET['q']);
  $term = taxonomy_get_term($parts(2));
  if ($term && $term->tid) {
    $node_count = db_result(db_query('SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM {term_node} WHERE tid = %d', $term->tid));
    if ($node_count == 0) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    if (count(taxonomy_get_children($term->tid)) == 0) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
  }
}

return TRUE;
```

And for Drupal 7:

```
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric($arg(2))) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
  if ($term && $term->tid) {
    if (db_query('SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM {taxonomy_index} WHERE tid = :tid', array(':tid' => $term->tid))->fetchField() == 0) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    if (count(taxonomy_get_children($term->tid)) == 0) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
  }
}
return TRUE;
```

Comment: I am using D6. Your code always shows the block, im afraid this level of PHP is beyond me so I really dont know what to start tweeking.

Comment: Ive thought of another potential work around. If I could show a view on term pages but only if the term has no child terms, then I make this the view of nodes, and if empty then display the text.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487457/drupal-show-block-on-term-page-if-term-has-no-children

Comment: You could probably do that, I've updated the Drupal 6 code above though, try that first it might just work!

Comment: Its still displaying on every page. Im just pasting your code in exactly as it is and not adding anything, is that correct? Thanks

Comment: Yeah you should just be able to drop it in. Are you using a view for your taxonomy pages or just the standard `taxonomy/term/term-id` paths?

Comment: Im using a view in a block. Im not using the default views taxonomy page overide as it didnt work well with a breadcrumbs module. Instead for taxonomy pages ive removed the content area from the template, and my block is in a region Ive added.